# Appending NSString and NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to merge `NSString` and `NSMutableAttributedString` .

In below code i want to make **self.txtSearch** as custom bold size and color.

code -

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
SearchViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SearchViewCell"];
AutoSuggestModel *autoSuggestModel = [self.autoSuggestArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if ([[autoSuggestModel type] isEqualToString:@"product"] || [[autoSuggestModel type] isEqualToString:@"category"]){

    cell.lblText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ in %@", self.txtSearch , [autoSuggestModel label]] ;

}else{
    cell.lblText.text = [autoSuggestModel label];
}
return cell;
}
```

I could make bold particular string with below code. but i want to append both string.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *boldString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.txtSearch];
    NSRange boldRange = [[autoSuggestModel label]   rangeOfString:self.txtSearch];
    [boldString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16] range:boldRange];
    [cell.lblText setAttributedText: boldString];
```

Comment: please give you whole cellforrowatindevpath method

Comment: @jamil65able updated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A very cursory look at the [`NSString` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/) has a section called "combining strings" and a method called `stringByAppendingString:`

Using this method, it should be incredibly straight-forward to accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *boldString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] 
    initWithString:[self.txtSearch stringByAppendingString:yourMutableString]];
```

Comment: hi i could not pass boldString in cell directly .. could u update your answer by my code where i have to change

Comment: The containing method that is setting a mutable string is irrelevant. Whether it is in `viewDidLoad` or `cellForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't matter. You need to either rephrase your question to what you actually want, or need to be much more clear about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

update you method like bellow

```
if ([[autoSuggestModel type] isEqualToString:@"product"] || [[autoSuggestModel type] isEqualToString:@"category"]){

        cell.textLabel.attributedText = [self getBoldText:cell withSearch:@"search text" withAutoSuggestModel:@"autoSuggestModel"];

    }else{
        cell.lblText.text = [autoSuggestModel label];
   }
```

//check above code by the following method

```
-(NSMutableAttributedString*)getBoldText:(UITableViewCell*)cell withSearch:(NSString*)searchText withAutoSuggestModel:(NSString*)autoSuggestModelText{
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ in %@", searchText,autoSuggestModelText];
cell.textLabel.text = title;
UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];

NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color,NSFontAttributeName:font};

NSMutableAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:cell.textLabel.attributedText];
[attrStr addAttributes:attrs range:[title rangeOfString:autoSuggestModelText]];
return attrStr;
```

}

Comment: how will u add merged string in cell. please could u update

Comment: where locate NSMutableAttributedString?

Comment: @ jamil65able  that s self.txtSearch

Comment: what s bold string in cell.

Comment: NSMutableAttributedString

Comment: -(void)attributedText  what s this? where do u call this cell

Comment: does "[autoSuggestModel label]" return NSString?

Comment: please update you code and i hope you will get success this time

Comment: did you check
"cell.textLabel.attributedText" i updated?